# Where is the .ebextensions folder in .NET for AWS elastic beanstalk Linux

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-web-services, .net-5

I am trying to upload a .NET application using visual studio 2019. This uploads, however, I need to make config changes in the .ebextensions folder. This is not showing up in visual studio. Where is the .ebextensions folder in my .NET application?

[image]

In Windows explorer
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be in the root of your project. I don't think it's created by default, so if it isn't there you need to create it. See the details of adding it to a .NET project [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/deployment-beanstalk-custom-netcore.html#tkv-deploy-beanstalk-custom-netcore-ebextensions).

Comment: It says "To include .ebextensions in an ASP.NET Core application, add the .ebextensions directory to the include section under publishOptions in the project.json file." . I cant find an include section or a publish options in any of the json files. I dont have a project.json or a schedularapp.json

Comment: I'm not a .NET developer, it may be that the project.json file is only for ASP.NET and not .NET core projects. At any rate you should start by creating the .ebextensions folder in the root of the project. It obviously doesn't exist yet from looking at your screenshots.

Comment: I've created the .ebextensions folder at the root of the project. But I need to now create the config file. Do you know where I can get a template of that? The link shows it for IIS but I need It to be for a Linux .net Nginx template.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for it via the Visual Studio Solutions Explorer, it probably **won't show up unless you enable *Show All Files***.

You can find this option here:
[Show All Files button in VS 2019 sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9vj9.png)

Comment: I have all files showing but I can not see the .ebextensions folder

Comment: Can you see it in Windows Explorer? Have you created the folder? If not, you will need to create it.

Comment: No, I still cant see it. I've added a print screenshot of what it looks like in windows explorer.

Comment: Then just go ahead and create the folder - you should be good to go.